# Load multiple files from one server using the same urlconnection

Tags: android, download, urlconnection

I am quite new to **Android/Java** developing. Currently I try to develop an app which displays the menu of several canteens. 
The URLs where the relevant information is stored looks like this (only example):

```
http://canteen-example.com/canteen-munich/14.csv  ("14" represents week of year)
http://canteen-example.com/canteen-berlin/14.csv
http://canteen-example.com/canteen-cologne/14.csv
...
```

Currently I download these files using a own `HttpUrlConnection` for each URL. It works ok but it is a little bit slow, when the connection of the phone is weak. I recognized, that in this case the most time elapses while connecting to the server and downloading the file is pretty fast (only plain text).

My method which I call for each URL (in a background tread) looks like this:

```
private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        //I want to connect only once to the server which they have all in common and not for each URL
        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();

        statusCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        is = conn.getInputStream();

        return readIt(is);
    }
    finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}
```

But now to me the question arises whether it is possible to connect only once to this particular server (it is the same for all URLs) and then download these ".csv" files from the different paths?

Thanks